# Join across different servers in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to perform an `INNER JOIN` across different servers in SQL Server 2008?

Is it possible without using `sp_addlinkedserver`?

Comment: You can try `OPENROWSET`

Comment: Why would you not want to use linked servers?

Comment: Permission not available to perform add linked server. That's why I was seeking other options.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be your best option:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms141775(v=sql.100).aspx